# iMacros + Javascript - How to refresh on page timeout?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I searched throughout but was unable to find a solution to this issue.

I have an iMacros .js that goes through a .CSV file with the following structure (URL, Value) and:
1. Visits the URL.
2. Inputs the specific value into a field.

Rinse. Repeat.

However, even with TIMEOUT value set to max, there are still occasions where the page will fail to load. I could set ERRORIGNORE to YES but then I would miss out on several pages on the list and I wouldn't know about it.

As such, what I am searching for is for code that will let me run my macro, and in case the page times out, refreshes it and runs the macro again without skipping a line in the CSV.

Here's how my .js looks:

```
for (i = 1; i <= count_of_lines; i++) { //The amount of times the Macro will loop should be defined here.
iimSet("i", i) //Set "i" so it is able to extract the nest row from the .csv file

var Macro;

Insert_Rating = "CODE:" //Need to use code here so that iMacros knows that the code will start
Macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
Macro += "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE FILENAME.csv" + "\n";
Macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
Macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120" + "\n";
Macro += "URL GOTO=URL{{!COL1}}" + "\n";
Macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
Macro += "TAG POS={{!COL2}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:" + "\n";

}
iimPlay(Macro);
```

I also tried with

```
var ret = iimPlay(Macro)
if (ret<0) {
iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH");
} else {
iimPlay(Macro);
}
```

But what happens here is that the code will check once (at the start of the if) and then attempt to run through the entire CSV if the initial condition is true.

I would need a way to check at each line of the CSV if the page timed out.

Perhaps this has a simple solution, but my coding skills are extremely basic.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost there. What you need to do is add some logic to get the field that you want to set. If the field is not found, retry.

This is the solution that I could think of:

```
var count_of_lines = 10;
var max_retries = 3;
var macro = '';

for (i = 1; i <= count_of_lines; i++) {

    var retries = max_retries;

    while (retries > 0) {
        macro = "TAB T=1" + "\n";
        macro += "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE FILENAME.csv" + "\n";
        macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
        macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120" + "\n";
        macro += "URL GOTO=URL{{!COL1}}" + "\n";
        macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
        // trying to extract the field..
        macro += "TAG POS={{!COL2}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT: EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";

        iimSet('i', i);
        iimPlayCode(macro);

        if (iimGetLastExtract() != '#EANF#' && iimGetLastExtract().trim().length != 0) {
            // found the field, do some logic here..
            // don't forget to break..

            break;          
        } else {
            // if the field could not be found, retry..
            retry--;
        }   
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey there firmanelhakim, thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question.
I tried the code you suggested, but unfortunately I think that the condition in the if statement is never being met, and as such the code just keeps refreshing the page.
I checked what the content of the condition was by using:
  window.alert(iimGetLastExtract().trim().length);
Even after tinkering with it a bit, it consistently comes back as 0.
So my line of thought is that the extract command is not actually happening (You're really just adding that string into the macro variable), so condition is always false

Answer (score 0):

Quick update: I actually got it to work the way it needed to in the end. :)

```
var count_of_lines = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter number of lines in the CSV file.","Please enter a number..."));
var DataSource = "/Users/Username/iMacros/Datasources/" + window.prompt("Please enter the name of the file.","");
var Load_Csv = "";
var Timeouts = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(count_of_lines); i++) {
    iimDisplay("The script has run through " + i + " lines out of a total of " + count_of_lines + "."); //Provide feedback about progress.
    iimDiplay("The script has timed out a total of " + Timeouts + " times." ); //Provide feedback about total timeouts.

        iimSet("i", i); //Necessary to make the attribution of i here.
        iimSet("DataSource", DataSource); //Necessary to make the attribution of DataSource here.
        Load_Csv = "TAB T=1 \n";
        Load_Csv += "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE {{DataSource}} \n";
        Load_Csv += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}} \n";
        Load_Csv += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120 \n";
        Load_Csv += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}} \n";
        iimPlayCode(Load_Csv);


        iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT"); //We are checking to see if the attribute exists (its length is >0)


        if (iimGetLastExtract() != '#EANF#' && iimGetLastExtract().trim().length != 0) {
            // Condition is met (Field exists = Page loaded correctly)

            iimSet("i", i); //Necessary to make the attribution of i here.
            iimSet("DataSource", DataSource);  //Necessary to make the attribution of DataSource here.
            Insert_Rating = "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE {{DataSource}} \n";
            Insert_Rating += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}} \n";
            Insert_Rating += "TAG POS={{!COL2}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT: \n";
            iimPlayCode(Insert_Rating); //Run the macro

        } 
        else 
        {
            // if the field could not be found, retry..
            iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH");
            i--; //If the load fails, you should subtract from i in order to make sure that you're not skipping a row in the .csv
            Timeouts++; //Adds to the timeouts counter.

        }
}
```